# What steps should I take to properly run 'bpftool struct_ops register xxx.o'?

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I compiled bpftool and bpf selftest suite inside of Linux mainline (2d1bcbc6cd70),
but when I invoke:
bpftool struct_ops register bpf_cubic.bpf.o

the command line fail with:
libbpf: struct_ops init_kern: struct tcp_congestion_ops data is not
found in struct bpf_struct_ops_tcp_congestion_ops
libbpf: failed to load object 'bpf_cubic.bpf.o'

The host OS I used to compile the kernel and bpf is Ubuntu 23.04, the
guest OS that I run bpftool is Ubuntu 22.04.

Or, can you teach me how to prepare an environment that can successfully run
"bpftool struct_ops register xxx.o"
(A few words of description of OS version (Ubuntu/CentOS/Suse for etc)
and example kernel .config is OK)

I tried bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux
and bpf_struct_ops_tcp_congestion_ops is:

```
[64291] STRUCT 'bpf_struct_ops_tcp_congestion_ops' size=256 vlen=3
        'refcnt' type_id=298 bits_offset=0
        'state' type_id=64117 bits_offset=32
        'data' type_id=63569 bits_offset=512
```

Answer (score 0):

when I construct the kernel package, I found lots of following warnings:

```
WARN: multiple IDs found for 'task_struct': 241, 21719 - using 241
WARN: multiple IDs found for 'vm_area_struct': 360, 21750 - using 360
WARN: multiple IDs found for 'file': 805, 21789 - using 805
WARN: multiple IDs found for 'cgroup': 666, 21819 - using 666
WARN: multiple IDs found for 'inode': 928, 21936 - using 928
WARN: multiple IDs found for 'path': 960, 21965 - using 960
```

These warnings lead me to:
Link: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/ZBovCrMXJk7NPISp@aurel32.net/T/

So, I upgraded my pahole from [1], and construct the kernel package
again, now I can successfully invoke
bpftool struct_ops register bpf_cubic.bpf.o

[1] https://github.com/acmel/dwarves.git